# Example of how pass by value-result works in Prolog

Tags: prolog, parameter-passing

I'm new to Prolog and I am aware of how pass by value-result works. However, I noticed that there's a lack of learning materials for Prolog and would like to see an example of how it works in this language.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is: it doesn't.

In standard terms, you always and only "pass by reference". The objects you pass-by-reference are the *terms* (these are directed, possibly cyclic graphs, generally trees), and they are globally visible (possibly modulo optimizations for strings, atoms, numbers etc).

So when you call this goal:

```
?- member(X,[1,2,3]).
```

the predicate `member/2` receives a reference to an "empty cell" in a global storage area, above named by the variable name `X` (and it will try to fill it with something useful), and a reference to a structure, here, written `[1,2,3]` probably in the global storage area.

On return, the value for `X`, filled by `member/2`, is printed:

```
?- member(X,[1,2,3]).
X = 1 ;
...
```

As for return values, in standard terms, a called predicate (expressed by an *atomic goal* like `p(X,Y)`) can either return true (signifying that "the predicate succeeded" / "the goal was proved" / "the goal can be labeled logically TRUE") or false (signifying that "the proof of the predicate failed" / "there is no proof for this goal" / "there is no reason to label this goal logically TRUE"). Alternatively it can throw an exception.

Note that there is no way in Prolog to express "the goal can be labeled logically FALSE" (even though Prolog may print arrogantly `false` in response to a query), although there is "negation as failure", but that's for another question.

Comment: *(even though Prolog may print arrogantly `false` in response to a query)* Note that `false` here is a built-in predicate. An answer `false` simply says that in stead of the actual query, you could have typed `false` instead. How this relates to arrogance is not clear to me.

Comment: @false Because if you see it at the toplevel, you would it read it as "this goal is `false`", which evidently evokes strong logical falsity (some toplevels more humbly say "fail" I understand).

Comment: Accordingly, you should also have problems with `true` which `fail`-saying top levels do. Even more so, since SWI does not show "floundering" goals or inconsistent constraints by default.

Comment: the `member(X,[1,2,3]).` could conceivably be working with full term copying. `member(1,[Y,2,Y])`, OTOH, is much harder to imagine to be working with full term copying implementation. so could be a better example.